# Simple If else on count- show different h5's

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to show two different bits of code depending on the value of count.

For example if count equals 1, I want to show this code:

```html
<h5>person has visited</h5>
```

and if it is more, I want to show

```html
<h5>people have visited</h5>
```

Here is my current code:

```html
<h5 class="visitor-count count">{{ $place->visitors->count()}}</h5>
<h5 class="visitor-count count-text">people have visited</h5>
```

```js
$('.visit').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var buttonToChange = $(this);
    var $this = $(this);

    $.ajax({})
    .done(function() {
        if(buttonToChange.hasClass('btn-visited')){
            buttonToChange.addClass('btn-not-visited');
            buttonToChange.removeClass('btn-visited');
            buttonToChange.html('Visited?');
            count = $this.siblings('.count');
            count.html(parseInt(count.html()) - 1);
        } else {
            buttonToChange.addClass('btn-visited');
            buttonToChange.removeClass('btn-not-visited');
            buttonToChange.html("I've Visited <i class='fas fa-check'>");
            count = $this.siblings('.count');
            count.html(parseInt(count.html()) +1);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Some of your variables aren't declared. Could you provide all of your JS code?

Comment: just edited, with missing code

Comment: Where are your buttons? Are the `h5` elements supposed to be them? If so, it looks like you might not even be selecting the right elements to assign the click handler to to begin with ... Please go read [mcve], and then provide a _proper_ example showing the problem.

Comment: No the button is not the h5. Should it matter the buttons are missing. The thing I want is simple. Which is an if else statement on count. The on click shows what the button is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here but :

- I added a button according to the code in your if/else
- I declared the `count` variable, which wasn't declared.
- I hard coded a count of 2 previous visitors instead of your PHP code. You're going to have to change that.
- I added a simple if/else block to test if the count equals 1 and change the message, the way you wanted :

> For example if count equals 1, I want to show this code:
>
> `<h5>person has visited</h5>`

- I removed the $.ajax call because it didn't serve any purpose.

Does it behave the way you want it to behave?

```js
$('.visit').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var buttonToChange = $(this);
    var $this = $(this);
    var count;

    $.ajax('http://www.google.fr')
        .done(function() {
            if (buttonToChange.hasClass('btn-visited')) {
                buttonToChange.addClass('btn-not-visited');
                buttonToChange.removeClass('btn-visited');
                buttonToChange.html('Visited?');
                count = $this.siblings('.count');
                count.html(parseInt(count.html()) - 1);
            } else {
                buttonToChange.addClass('btn-visited');
                buttonToChange.removeClass('btn-not-visited');
                buttonToChange.html("I've Visited <i class='fas fa-check'>");
                count = $this.siblings('.count');
                count.html(parseInt(count.html()) + 1);
            }

            // simple if / else to change the text in 'count-text' depending on the value of 'count'
            if (parseInt(count.html()) === 1) {
                $(".count-text").html("person has visited");
            } else {
                $(".count-text").html("people has visited");
            }
        });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<button type="button" class="visit btn-visited">Visit</button>
<h5 class="visitor-count count">2</h5>
<h5 class="visitor-count count-text">people have visited </h5>
```